# Question about Green Card for L1 at port of entry

Tags: usa, immigration, l1-visa

I have previously been to the US for 4 times on a B1 visa. A couple of my stays were for 89 days. A couple of my stays were less than a month.

Now I am travelling to the US on an L1B visa. Any advice related to questions at port of entry will be helpful.

I read in one of the forums that there was a question about the green card by the CBP officer.

- Would you apply for GC?
- If given opportunity would you go for GC?

What would be the best way to answer questions?

**EDIT:** Please note that I am travelling with my wife and infant child. Both have valid L2 visas. It's their first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L-1 is not subject to the presumption of "immigrant intent". That means it's perfectly fine to have preconceived intent to immigrate on this trip when you get your L-1 visa or when you enter on L-1. Even if you intend to file Adjustment of Status the day after entering, that would be fine to disclose.

So you don't have to worry about any questions about immigrant intent, if there are any. Just answer honestly, and it won't affect your entry on L-1 no matter how you answer.

Comment: Thank you. Is this right way to answer? My employer may apply if my expertise required for long term.

Comment: @be_good_do_good those questions are about your intent.  A response about your employer could be seen as evasive.